# How do I disable the creation of the artifact-[build-no].json file?

Tags: json, jar, google-cloud-build

When I build a maven project from GitHub using Cloud Build  (resulting in jar files in a bucket) I get an extra file uploaded to my bucket that specifies what files have been built (artifacts-[build-no].json). The file has a unique name for every build, so the bucket gets filled up with loads of unwanted files. Is there a way to disable the creation of that file?

Answer (score 1):

I think the json is only generated when using the artifacts flag, such as:

```
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: 'gs://$PROJECT_ID/'
    paths: ['hello']
```

You could manually push to a bucket in a step with the `gsutil` cloud builder, without the helper syntax.  This would avoid the json creation.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gsutil

```
# Upload it into a GCS bucket.
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  args: ['cp', 'gopath/bin/hello', 'gs://$PROJECT_ID/hello']
```